# LogicApp deployment without overwriting API Connection properties

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-deployment

I am deploying few LogicApps from Visual Studio to Azure. All of them use same API Connections (FTP and File System). LogicApps have been previously downloaded from Cloud Explorer. Each time I deploy LogicApp to the cloud, API Connections properties are changed as well. Understandable, as each LogicApp contains those two API Connections with all details. I have tried to remove properties like `user name` and `password` from LogicApp JSON definition, but then properties are also changed and left without any value.

So the goal is to tell deployment process to deploy LogicApp and to use named API Connection `ftp1` with its properties defined in cloud as they are. This way there is no more need to update same password in every single LogicApp JSON file.

Comment: When deploying a logic app, you don't need to re-create the connection (i.e. you can reference existing connections under $connections parameter). It sounds like you are re-deploying your connections as well.

Comment: @SzymonWylezol Is there any documentation on this? I cannot find it within Azure Resource Deployment ones.